# No rule to make target--- while cross compiling

Tags: android, shared-libraries, android-build

I'm trying to include a fingerprint module. i placed all the .c and .h files in a new directory under /external/ and created an Android.mk file as

```
########## libdpfpdd ############
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := ldpfpdd
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libdpfpdd.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

########### libdpfj ##############

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := ldpfj
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libdpfj.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

######### fingerprint ############

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE := fingerprint
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
  enrollment.c helpers.c identification.c \
  menu.c sample.c selection.c verification.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += ldpfpdd ldpfj
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

after this i tried to do cross compilation as
    make TARGET_PRODUCT=am335xevm_sk -j8 OMAPES=4.x
and got the error as

```
make: *** No rule to make target `out/target/product/am335xevm_sk/obj/lib/ldpfpdd.so', needed by `out/target/product/am335xevm_sk/obj/EXECUTABLES/fingerprint_intermediates/LINKED/fingerprint'.  Stop.
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Comment: Do you already have prebuilt libdpfpdd.so and libdpfj.so?

Comment: that i have placed in the same directory

Comment: i have changed the local module name to libdpfpdd and libdpfj and also changed them in LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES. and also made changes to the first two modules as

Comment: LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := .so
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := SHARED_LIBRARIES
#include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)

now i'm able to get the .so in the out/....directory but still running into error for both .so as 
prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.x/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: out/target/product/am335xevm_sk/obj/lib/libdpfpdd.so: unknown mandatory EABI object attribute 44